# Kotlin problem with understanding piece of code

Tags: kotlin

I've just started learning programming and I'm having a problem understanding a piece of code from a tutorial. Could anyone explain what the Kotlin code below does?

Thank you

```
fun f(i:Int, list:MutableList<Int>) : Boolean {
    for (number in list) {
        if (i % number == 0) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

fun main(args:Array<String>) {
    val result = mutableListOf<Int>()
    for (number in 2..100) {
        if (f(number, result)) {
            result.append(number)
        }   

       print(result.joinToString())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main method creates a new list of integers. In a loop from 2 to 200 it calls the function f with current number of the loop (number) and the list created.

The function checks if the number handed over can be divided by any number in the list. In case it can be divided, false is returned, else true.

If the number couldn't be divided then the number is stored inside the list.

So it is a simple algorithm to find prime numbers. The list stores all so far found prime numbers. And the function checks if the number can be divided by any of the prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`f(...)` checks whether i divides with any number in the list - if so, returns false.

`main(..)` loops through all numbers from 2..100 and adds numbers that don't divide with any number previously added to the list.

Basically, it will print all prime numbers between 2..100